# Sorting a multidimensional array in PHP by a numeric value

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have been stuck on this problem for a couple of days now. I just can't seem to wrap my head around what seemingly should be a easy problem.

Here is the array, and I want to sort it by temperature. Descending.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Sandnes
        [latitude] => 58.85244
        [longitude] => 5.73521
        [temperature] => 12.0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Sola
        [latitude] => 58.88854
        [longitude] => 5.65285
        [temperature] => 12.3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Kleppe
        [latitude] => 58.77303
        [longitude] => 5.63329
        [temperature] => 12.1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Hommersåk
        [latitude] => 58.93167
        [longitude] => 5.85111
        [temperature] => 11.3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Ålgård
        [latitude] => 58.76417
        [longitude] => 5.85253
        [temperature] => 10.9
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => Stavanger
        [latitude] => 58.97005
        [longitude] => 5.73332
        [temperature] => 11.9
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => Tananger
        [latitude] => 58.93618
        [longitude] => 5.5741
        [temperature] => 12.5
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [name] => Bryne
        [latitude] => 58.73536
        [longitude] => 5.64766
        [temperature] => 12.4
    )
```

I have tried multiple different solutions with the many different sorting functions that PHP comes with, but with no luck.

I have seen variants of this question, but their answers always vary. After trying to implement some of the solutions I have seen, and failed, I'm hoping some of you may be of assistance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994075/sort-multidimensional-arrays-by-sub-array-key-value

Comment: @ukritic: I will inspect your linked solution, and play around with the suggested answers. But please note that what you linked me to, is still an unsolved problem.

Comment: easy to do with usort()

Comment: Check this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

As first suggested by ukratic, this worked great.

```
function compare_temp($a,$b)
{
    if($a['temperature'] == $b['temperature']) return 0;
    return ($a['temperature'] < $b['temperature']) ? 1 : -1;
}
usort($places, 'compare_temp');
```

Comment: This can be simplified even more by simply subtracting the two temperatures. Note that the return value doesn't have to be -1, 0, or 1. It can be any number less than, equal to, or greater than zero - the exact value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

An easy fix with `usort()`:

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b){
  return ($b["temperature"]-$a["temperature"]);
});
```

The PHP manual examples compare in the order `$a, $b` to give an ascending result. This suggestion compares `$b,$a` to reverse the sort order.

Here's the PHP reference: [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Try this hope it helps you

```
$array = $your_array

foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $temperature[$key] = $row['temperature'];
 }
 array_multisort($temperature, SORT_DESC, $array);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($array);
 echo "</pre>";
```

See this small [**CODEPAD DEMO**](http://codepad.org/pBPgi4nc)